# how can i display an image wit nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

am trying to insert an image in my main component everything is working fine, my alt atribute is displaying but the image in not displaying on the browser. please what am i doing wrong

```
import port from "../public/port.png";

export default function Main() {
return (
    <section className="">
        <div className="">
            <img src={port} alt="illustration" />
        </div>
    </section>
);
}
```

Comment: You could try Next.js' [image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image), or you can simply use the relative path to the image.

Comment: you used width and height for image ? if worked this is not good , you must use Image-Nextjs . When use Nextjs

Comment: if your path is true, you have to use width and height attributes.

Answer (score 0):

if your file exist in public folder, then you dont have to import it. it is accessible globally.

```
export default function Main() {
return (
    <section className="">
        <div className="">
            <img src="/port.png" alt="illustration" />
        </div>
    </section>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `image` tag

```js
<img src="/public/port.png" alt="your alt">
```

[next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) has been introduced since v.10.0.0. You can use either

- Statically imported

```js
import port from "../public/port.png";

<Image
   src={port}
   alt="your alt"
   // width={500} automatically provided
   // height={500} automatically provided
   // blurDataURL="data:..." automatically provided
   // placeholder="blur" // Optional blur-up while loading
/>
```

- Path string (internal URL | external URL)

```js
// Example external source
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['example.com'],
  },
}

<Image
  src="https://example.com/image1.png"
  // ...
/>
```